# Application properties as static variables or instance variables with singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, properties

I need to read application properties from a .properties file to a class which should work as a single point to application properties. For such a class what is the recommended way: define those properties as static variables or as instance variables with singleton pattern?

I have a `myapp.properties` file in format **key=value**. Suppose there are 2 application properties defined in this file:

> Company=ABC 
>   BatchSize=1000

On application startup I will be reading this file into a class `ApplicationProperties`. I will be using this class whenever I need to use application properties.

I have 2 options:

**Option 1:** Define the application properties as static variables:

```
public class ApplicationProperties {
   private static String COMPANY;
   private static int BATCH_SIZE;

   static {
      // read myapp.properties file and populate static variables COMPANY & BATCH_SIZE
   }

   private ApplicationProperties() {}

   public static String getCompany() {
      return COMPANY;
   }
   public static int getBatchSize() {
      return BATCH_SIZE;
   }
}
```

**Option 2:** Define the application properties as instance variables:

```
public class ApplicationProperties {
   private static ApplicationProperties INSTANCE = new ApplicationProperties();

   private String company;
   private int batchSize;

   private ApplicationProperties() {
      // read myapp.properties file and populate instance variables company & batchSize
   }

   public static ApplicationProperties getInstance() {
      return INSTANCE;
   }

   public String getCompany() { 
      return this.company;
   }
   public int getBatchSize() {
      return this.batchSize;
   }
}
```

For Option 1 I would be accessing this way:

```
ApplicationProperties.getCompany();
ApplicationProperties.getBatchSize();
```

For Option 2 I would be accessing this way:

```
ApplicationProperties.getInstance().getCompany();
ApplicationProperties.getInstance().getBatchSize();
```

Which is preferable? And why?

If this question has been answered before please point to the answer.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a question anybody can answer. Either approach is fine. Do whichever one fits inside your brain the best. I would personally wonder why you think it needs to be a singleton at all, but that's just me.

Comment: What advantages do you see in the second way?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question.  If both approaches work (and more!  Try Spring injection to stick your property values wherever you need them!) then asking which one is "better" is asking for opinions.

Comment: I was looking at the standard way for application properties. Or the generally acceptable pattern developers use in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is slightly more complicated and verbose without offering any advantages, therefore Option 1 is better design.

IMHO this is not "opinion-based".

Comment: agree that I dont see any advantages in using Option 2 over Option 1